# Iterating in a points geodataframe and then check if point is inside polygon

Tags: python, spatial-analyst, geopandas, shapely

I'm trying to make a spatial verification.

I have a geodataframe with 245 points, and I'm having a bad time trying to check if they're inside a polygon or not.

I've been attempting this code, but I just won't work. As far as I understood, geodataframes are slightly different from dataframes when in a for loop.

```
for x in event_log_c.geometry:
    i = event_log_c.iloc[x].within(hexa)
    print(i)
```

After running this, it brings me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

`hexa` is the polygon geodataframe, and `event_log_c` is the 245 points geodataframe.

How can I make a spatial verification iterating a geodataframe? Are there any way of doing this?

Comment: My disired result is a simple "True" or "False" output for each row.

Comment: There are many answers to this question in GSE;  This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165413/2581) for example, without loop.

Comment: Thanks, Gene, but It wasn't what I was looking for. Luckly I found something that might fit well to me. I appreciate your help

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323479/geopandas-does-not-identify-points-inside-polygon?rq=1) post helped me solve my problem